# How to get the hardware ID in .net reactor 6.9.0?

Tags: licensing, net-reactor

As the title mention above, how can I obtain the Hardware ID for licensing purpose? Because the hardware ID generator tool has been removed in current version(6.9.0).

I have tried using the ID generated from other ID-generator downloaded online(SoftCo for example) but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the respective license.dll file contained within the SDK:

With the .NET library "License.dll" you are able to determine the current licensing status of your protected software at runtime. You only need to reference this library in your project and use the corresponding methods and properties. All methods and properties should be self explanatory. You don't need to select a license file. If a valid license file is available it will be used automatically to update the licensing status.

***Please note, the methods and properties of "License.dll" only return the correct values after you have protected your software.*** After protection the library "License.dll" is not needed anymore.

Content of "License.dll" in C#:

```
namespace License
{
    public enum EvaluationType
    {
        Trial_Days,
        Runtime_Minutes
    }

    public class Status
    {

        // Methods
        static Status();
        private Status();
        public static bool CheckConfirmationCode(string harwareID, string confirmationCode);


        public static string GetHardwareID(bool Board, bool CPU, bool HDD, bool MAC);




        public static string InvalidateLicense();
        public static void LoadLicense(string filename);
        public static void LoadLicense(byte[] license);
        public static bool ReactivateLicense(string code);

        // Properties
        public static bool Evaluation_Lock_Enabled { get; set; }
        public static int Evaluation_Time { get; set; }
        public static int Evaluation_Time_Current { get; set; }
        public static EvaluationType Evaluation_Type { get; set; }
        public static DateTime Expiration_Date { get; set; }
        public static bool Expiration_Date_Lock_Enable { get; set; }
        public static bool Hardware_Lock_Enabled { get; set; }
        public static string HardwareID { get; set; }
        public static SortedList KeyValueList { get; set; }
        public static byte[] License { get; set; }
        public static string License_HardwareID { get; set; }
        public static bool Licensed { get; set; }
        public static int Number_Of_Instances { get; set; }
        public static bool Number_Of_Instances_Lock_Enable { get; set; }
        public static int Number_Of_Uses { get; set; }
        public static int Number_Of_Uses_Current { get; set; }
        public static bool Number_Of_Uses_Lock_Enable { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Make sure you use the same parameters as you use when protecting the assembly eg The HDD Serial is not used by default in the protection settings so you would use GetHardwareID(true, true, false, true).